# Creating comma-separated text after applying regex on excel column

Tags: javascript, php, regex, excel, csv

I have a Excel column and i need to convert it into CSV. I have been given a javascript regex to apply on the column values:

```
var regex = new RegExp("[^a-z0-9',.]+","gi");
return input.replace(regex, "_").replace(/_+/g, "_").replace(/^_|_$|^\/|\/$|'|,/g, "");
```

How can I convert excel columns into a javascript array so that I can loop through array values and apply the regex to save it into the array again and then create a csv from the array.

I just have one column in my excel. Any suggestion or best way to solve this? I can use PHP or C# but I am not sure how to convert this javascript regex into php or c#. Or at least some one tell me what should be the best solution to solve this.

This is the sample data from my excel sheet i have one column, `str name`, and it has values like:

```
strName
ABC
Nike & Sony etc
THE METEORS
```

Comment: Can you show us your code to extract the data from the excel and show us what the value of `input` is?

Comment: i have edit the question and i am not sure where to start from how can i convert excel column into javascript array so that i can loop through the values

Comment: Do you have **any** code yet for reading the excel?

Comment: i have PHP code and C# code to read excel column but i am not sure how to convert apply this javascript regex if i choose php or c# because this regex is in javascript

Comment: Can you show us how the data looks like when you get it out of your excel file? We cannot help you if we don't know what data we are talking about. Is it one string? Is it an array? Is it a list?

Comment: my excel sheet has one column strName and it has all string values can you see my question again i have included sample data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to convert anything to Javascript as there is a built-in function to create CSV in PHP: [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). It takes an array as input and prints it to an output file as comma-separated data, with a carriage return at the end.

Your data appears to be an array of lines, so you will need to convert each line into an array for use with `fputcsv`.

```
# input data
$lines = array(
    'strName',
    'ABC',
    'Nike & Sony etc',
    'THE METEORS');

# open the output file
$fh = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($lines as $l) {
    # convert the line to an array and pass it to fputcsv
    fputcsv($fh, array($l));
}
fclose($fh);
```

file.csv now contains:

```
strName
ABC
"Nike & Sony etc"
"THE METEORS"
```

Comment: thanks but i need to implement that regex on the array values and then save it in csv can you see my regex? or how can i convert it in a php regex?

Comment: You don't need to implement that regex -- PHP does it all for you in `fputcsv`. The regex is a hack created because javascript doesn't have a native function for handling csv, unlike PHP.

Comment: one last question what this regex is basically doing ? can you explain this

Comment: Your regex is first replacing any non-alphanumeric characters (excluding comma, full stop, and `'`) with `_`, then replacing any `__` with `_`, and then trimming off any `_` at the beginning or end of the string, removing any `/` characters (which would already have been removed in the first regex), and removing `,` and `'`. It looks like the last `replace` was added as an afterthought as it duplicates work that has already been done.

Comment: so fputcsv does everything which is written in javascript regex right? i see you have made an array and then creating a output file. right now i have an excel sheet with the column 'strname' and it has values how can i create that excel column into an php array?

Comment: `fputcsv` does all that and more!! It's amazing. ;)  Read in your file using `file_get_contents`, and then create an array using `explode` to split it up by the line endings. BTW, Excel does allow you to export your data as comma-separated values. Was that not an option here?

Comment: i found this line and can you suggest me is this the good option to make an array using this $lines = file('/path/to/file.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

Comment: Yes, that is a good option. There are lots of ways to read in files in PHP, so choose the one that is best for your situation (probably this one in this case!).